# one liner command to find files and print specific line

Tags: bash

I would like to run a find command to get file list, then run sed command to show specific line content on screen. it can be done by below bash script.

```
flst=`find . -name zipfile.py`
for f in $flst; do
    sed -n '756p' $f
done
```

How can I use one liner command to implement the same in bash command line?

Comment: Something like `find . -name zipfile.py -exec sed -n '756p' {} \;`. This is untested but probably close.

Comment: In bash, you don't need `find` for this, provided that you turn on the  _globstar_ option. a `sed -n 756p **/zipfile.py` should be sufficient then (untested!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gene suggested, I have tested this command, it works:

```bash
find . -name zipfile.py -exec sed -n '756p' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the meaning of the last part "{} \;"?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove newlines and specific ones replace by `;`.

```
flst=`find . -name zipfile.py` ; for f in $flst; do sed -n '756p' $f ; done
```